# How to create a date object for tomorrow at 8am

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nsdatecomponents

I am normally pretty good with this, but I am having trouble with the `NSDate` object. I need a `NSDate` object set for tomorrow at 8am (relatively). How would I do this and what is the simplest method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's how [WWDC 2011 session 117 - Performing Calendar Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=117) taught me:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date] ;

NSDateComponents* tomorrowComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
tomorrowComponents.day = 1 ;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ;
NSDate* tomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:tomorrowComponents toDate:now options:0] ;

NSDateComponents* tomorrowAt8AMComponents = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:tomorrow] ;
tomorrowAt8AMComponents.hour = 8 ;
NSDate* tomorrowAt8AM = [calendar dateFromComponents:tomorrowAt8AMComponents] ;
```

Too bad iOS doesn't have `[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"tomorrow at 8:00 am"]`. Thanks, [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy), for pointing that out.

Comment: Based on the tags, this question appears to be for iOS. The `dateWithNaturalLanguageString:` method is only for OSX, not iOS.

Comment: Ok, so now it's adding 8 hours I think, but on the 8am one it isn't adding the day, it's going back to today. Although on the tomorrow only one it is for tomorrow... here is my console log with all three dates http://cl.ly/NPH5

Comment: Instead of logging the NSDate, can you [use an NSDateFormatter to create an NSString](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EXWgO.png) and log that?

Comment: I can see from your log that you're in the Pacific Time Zone (UTC-8), because 2013-03-06 21:06 in your local time (the timestamp at the beginning of your log) equals 2013-03-07 05:06 in UTC (your log's text following "Now:").  When you NSLog an NSDate, the date displays in UTC, so 8:00am displays as 16:00.  That code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 2.1**:

```
    let now = NSDate()
    let tomorrowComponents = NSDateComponents()
    tomorrowComponents.day = 1

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    if let tomorrow = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(tomorrowComponents, toDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchFirst) {

        let flags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Era, .Year, .Month, .Day]
        let tomorrowValidTime: NSDateComponents = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: tomorrow)
        tomorrowValidTime.hour = 7

        if let tomorrowMorning = calendar.dateFromComponents(tomorrowValidTime) {
            return tomorrowMorning
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3+**

```
private func tomorrowMorning() -> Date? {
    let now = Date()
    var tomorrowComponents = DateComponents()
    tomorrowComponents.day = 1
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    if let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: tomorrowComponents, to: now) {
        let components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.era, .year, .month, .day]
        var tomorrowValidTime = calendar.dateComponents(components, from: tomorrow)
        tomorrowValidTime.hour = 7
        if let tomorrowMorning = calendar.date(from: tomorrowValidTime)  {
            return tomorrowMorning
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```