# Update Every Day in swift syntax

Tags: ios, swift

Working on a quote app, and as a beginner I decided to rule out using CoreData and Sqlite in my app. Therefore I decided to try a collection and change the text label.I have a collection stored in an array. I'm trying to achieve the text changing every 24 hours and it changes at 8:00 A.M E.S.T (so 8 A.M to 8 A.M)I would like the outline to be something like

```
quoteindex = 0
if(time_elasped:24 hours something about 8:00 A.M EST) {
quote.text = quoteCollection.quoteArray[quoteIndex]
quoteindex++ (next quote in array)
}
```

How would I organize something like this in terms of syntax? Would I use another loop?

Comment: Why can't you just set up repeating `NSTimer` to achieve that?

Comment: Can you show in the answer section how to do something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to use NSUserDefaults to store an NSDictionary containing the last time and index when the user last retrieved a quote.

**in viewDidLoad:** (or make into standalone function - checkLastRetrieval())

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let lastRetrieval = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("lastRetrieval") {
    if let lastDate = lastRetrieval["date"] as? NSDate {
        if let index = lastRetrieval["index"] as? Int {
           if abs(lastDate.timeIntervalSinceNow) > 86400 { // seconds in 24 hours
            // Time to change the label
            var nextIndex = index + 1

            // Check to see if next incremented index is out of bounds
            if self.myQuoteArray.count <= nextIndex {
                // Move index back to zero? Behavior up to you...
                nextIndex = 0
            }

            self.myLabel.text = self.myQuoteArray[nextIndex]

            let lastRetrieval : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
               "date" : NSDate(),
               "index" : nextIndex
             ]

             userDefaults.setObject(lastRetrieval, forKey: "lastRetrieval")
             userDefaults.synchronize()
        }
        // Do nothing, not enough time has elapsed to change labels
      }
   }
} else {

  // No dictionary found, show first quote
  self.myLabel.text = self.myQuoteArray.first!

  // Make new dictionary and save to NSUserDefaults
  let lastRetrieval : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
    "date" : NSDate(),
    "index" : 0
  ]

  userDefaults.setObject(lastRetrieval, forKey: "lastRetrieval")
  userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

You can be more specific using NSDate if you want to ensure a specific time (like 8AM) or make sure that there is a unique quote for every actual day (Monday, Tuesday, etc). This example simply changes the label if the user has seen a quote more than 24 hours ago.

Check out the docs for [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/).

**EDIT**:
If you wanted to notify the user at 8AM the next day of a new quote you could send a [local notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) to the user.

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()

notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: someTimeInterval)
notification.timeZone = NSCalender.currentCalendar().timeZone

notification.alertBody = "Some quote" // or "Check the app"
notiication.hasAction = true
notification.alertAction = "View"

application.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

You would have to calculate the timeInterval to be whatever time is left to 8AM the next day. Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262058/2881524  (It's objective-c but you should be able to figure it out)

**EDIT**

To execute code when your view enters the foreground you need to post a notification in your AppDelegate's applicationWillEnterForeground method. And add an observer for that notification in your view controller.

in **AppDelegate**

```
let notification = NSNotification(name: "CheckLastQuoteRetrieval", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
```

in **ViewController**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("checkLastRetrieval"), name: "CheckLastQuoteRetrieval", object: nil)
    checkLastRetrieval()

}
```

Comment: your index and next index is making me very confused... Can you furthermore explain?

Comment: index is the previous index (the quote that was previously accessed) and nextIndex is just that incremented by 1 (the index to be displayed).

Comment: thx for reply. Lastly I would like to ask how would I be able to set 8:00 AM For the function instead of the 24 hour from retrieval

Comment: Hmm, Thanks for the update, but it doesn't seem to work in my ios simulator. I've waited well past 24 hours and the quote doesn't seem to be updated. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Try debugging using a shorter amount of time....you shouldn't have to wait 24 hours to see if it's working.

Comment: Also, are you reloading your view? If your app is only one view than try putting this in viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: hey gmat, thanks for the fast reply, tried to debug when I added this question and it doesn't seem to work (i did 1 second in the statement), my app has multiple views.

Comment: I just ran it on a device and on the simulator. The code works fine. Although I manually called the function. The issue you're having (I suspect I do not know how you're structuring your app) is that you want the code to execute when the app enters the foreground from the background. To do that you need to post a notification in your app delegates "applicationWillEnterForeground" method and add an observer to your viewcontroller. viewWillAppear does not run when your app enters the foreground from background. I will add an edit that shows the code for this.

Comment: perhaps take this to chat?

Comment: Would love to help you more with this but I'm bogged down right now with another project. I would suggest you read up on notifications. Also check out bitfountains course on iOS, really great course.

Comment: it works like a charm after some minor fixes THANKS!

Comment: great response. I know it will help some users eventually, upvoted and marked as correct! sure will help out some other users someday

Comment: No problem, glad to help