# Generate Quote Everyday from .plist File

Tags: ios, swift, plist

This question is related to: [Update Every Day in swift syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666734/update-every-day-in-swift-syntax) except instead of an array, it is a .plist file that has all of the quotes and authors as strings.

How can I get my app to change its quote everyday at 8 in the morning, by selecting a random quote from the .plist file that is set up?

```
    //=========================//
    //=========New Quote=======//
    //=======================//

    // Generates Random Number
    func randomNumber(arrayLength: Int) -> Int {
        let unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(arrayLength)
        let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)


        return randomNumber
    }

    // Importing Quotes plist File
    let BooksQuoteScreen = ImportBookList(FileName: "BookList")

    // Selects Quote
    let chosenQuote: String! = BooksQuoteScreen.array[randomNumber(BooksQuoteScreen
        .count())] as! String
    let chosenAuthor = BooksQuoteScreen.dict[chosenQuote]! as String

    // Assigns Quote & Author to IBOutlet

    Quote = chosenQuote
    Author = chosenAuthor


    quoteDisplay.text = Quote
    authorDisplay.text = Author.uppercaseString

}
```

I actually have a timer on the background of the quote, that changes the background when it is 3pm in the afternoon. Could I use that same element to change the quote? Thanks in advance. If you need more information, please comment and I will update it immediately.

Comment: See the M in [mcve]?

Comment: yes, you can use same method...